android.intent.action.SET_ALARM is not working currently
import IntentLauncher, { IntentConstant } from 'react-native-intent-launcher';

export const SetAlarm = (Hour, Minute) => {
    const now = new Date()
    let currentHour = now.getHours()
    let currentMinute = now.getMinutes()

    // Dakikaya ekleme yap
    let newMinute = currentMinute + Minute;
    let additionalHours = Math.floor(newMinute / 60); // Eğer dakika 60'ı geçerse saati artır
    if(additionalHours > 0){
        newMinute = newMinute % 60; // Dakikayı 60'ın altında tut
    }

    // Saate ekleme yap
    let newHour = (currentHour + Hour + additionalHours) % 24; // 24 saat sisteminde kal

    console.log("Hour: " + newHour + " Minute: " + newMinute);
    const intentParams = {
      action: 'android.intent.action.SET_ALARM',
      extra: {
        'android.intent.extra.alarm.HOUR': parseInt(newHour),  // Saat
        'android.intent.extra.alarm.MINUTES': parseInt(newMinute),  // Dakika
        'android.intent.extra.alarm.SKIP_UI': true,  // UI'yi atla  
      }
    };
    try{
        IntentLauncher.startActivity(intentParams);
    }
    catch(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
};

But instead of the hour and minute I gave it, it automatically sets it to 11 o'clock.
How can I have it set at the hour and minute I choose? I couldn't find an exact example usage on the internet.

For Android security, it cannot be set automatically on some phones, it only redirects to the application screen.
